Emulator doesnt recieve push notifications from Cloud Messaging
I tried to connect Cloud Messaging to my application, having tried all the solutions, the notification still does not arrive. When I try to send something in the console, only this is written:
Here is manifest.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapp">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Myapp"

        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".SignUpActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CreatedWorkoutActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".CreatedWorkoutActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkoutMakerActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".WorkoutMakerActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Pop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"
            >
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".FCMNotificationService"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>




        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

    </application>

</manifest>

FCMNotificationService.java:
package com.example.myapp;


import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;


import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FCMNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        System.out.println("я тут");

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            // Show the notification
            String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();

            sendNotification (notificationTitle, notificationBody);

        }
    }


    private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        String channelId = "fcm_default_channel";
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }



}

And part from MainActivity that i added to solve this problem "Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.":
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Optionally set other channel settings such as lights, vibration, etc.
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        

Emulator's version:

Ive tried to add a lot of things to manifest, but nothing helped.

Declare the permission in your manifest like this (Android 13+):
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

Android Docs:
If your app targets Android 13 or higher, your app has complete control over when the permission dialog is displayed. Use this opportunity to explain to users why the app needs this permission, encouraging them to grant it.
If your app targets 12L (API level 32) or lower, the system shows the permission dialog the first time your app starts an activity after you create a notification channel, or when your app starts an activity and then creates its first notification channel. This is usually on app startup.
Referance: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission
Firebase Docs:
Notification permissions for apps targeting Android 12L (API level 32) or lower Android automatically asks the user for permission the first time your app creates a notification channel, as long as the app is in the foreground. However, there are important caveats regarding the timing of channel creation and permission requests:
If your app creates its first notification channel when it is running in the background (which the FCM SDK does when receiving an FCM notification), Android will not allow the notification to be displayed and will not prompt the user for the notification permission until the next time your app is opened. This means that any notifications received before your app is opened and the user accepts the permission will be lost.
We strongly recommend that you update your app to target Android 13+ to take advantage of the platform’s APIs to request permission. If that is not possible, your app should create notification channels before you send any notifications to the app in order to trigger the notification permission dialog and ensure no notifications are lost. See notification permission best practices for more information.
Referance: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

i added it, but nothing changed

Have u throughly referred this docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client? Maybe try changing the FCM library's version or the Android version and see if it works there.

Thank you, i added permission check in Oncreate and it worked
